# What is the simplest non-principal ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Let's restrict ourselves to commutative rings (not necessarily with unity).

Is there a simpler example of a non-principal ideal than $\langle a,x\rangle$ in $R[x]$, where $a\in R$ is not a unit (and therefore $R$ is not a field)? All other examples that come to mind involve more complicated polynomial rings and seem to be particular cases of the previous example.

Comment: How much more simple can you get??

Comment: That's what I'm asking.

Comment: Let $k$ be a field. In the ring of $k$-polynomials with no linear term, the ideal of elements with no constant term is nonprincipal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic example for a ring that is not a polynomial ring  is the ideal $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. I don't think there's going to be anything simpler if you rule out examples from polynomial rings.

But personally I find the conceptually simplest example is the ideal $(x,y)$ in $R[x,y]$, where $R$ can be any non-zero ring at all. It requires the least amount of thought to see that it is non-principal. However it fits into the pattern you've ruled out, since $R[x,y]=R[x][y]$.

Comment: dumb question: does the notation $(a,b)$ for defining an ideal represent the set $S = {ma+nb}$ for integers $m,n$? (in other words, the sum of all multiples of $a$ and $b$)

Comment: @JasonS: Not a dumb question at all. In general, if $R$ is a commutative ring, and $a,b\in R$, then the ideal $(a,b)$ of $R$ is the set
$$\{ra+sb:r,s\in R\}$$
(see [this section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Ideal_generated_by_a_set)). However, note that for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, that means $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is the set
$$\{(r_1+r_2\sqrt{-5})\cdot 2 + (s_1+s_2\sqrt{-5})\cdot(1+\sqrt{-5}):r_1+r_2\sqrt{-5}, s_1+s_2\sqrt{-5}\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\}$$
which is bigger than the set
$$\{m\cdot 2 + n\cdot(1+\sqrt{-5}):m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$

Comment: oh, so the notation $(a,b,c,...)$ is essentially a linear basis for the ideal, with both basis values and coefficients in the ring $R$?

Comment: @JasonS: That's a shaky comparison to make, because there will be relations between the "basis" elements of the ideal (whose more proper name would just be "generators"), whereas for a basis in a vector space, the whole point is that there is no relation between them. For example, the ideal $(4,6)$ inside $\mathbb{Z}$ is
$$\{4m+6n:m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
which is exactly the set of even numbers,
$$\{2x:x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
otherwise known as $(2)$. In general, for integers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, we have $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=(\gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n))$.

Comment: How do prove that $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is non principal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ ?

Comment: What exactly is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$?

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer to the comment of dafnahaktana above to the answer

> How do prove that $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is non principal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ ?

**Please** inform him, I have not enough reputation to add a comment.

The ideal $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ in the commutative ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is
\begin{align*}
&(2,1+\sqrt{-5})\\
=&\{2r_1+(1+\sqrt{-5})r_2:r_1,r_2\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] \}\\
=&\{2(r_{11}+r_{12}\sqrt{-5})+(1+\sqrt{-5})(r_{21}+r_{22}\sqrt{-5}):r_{11},r_{12},r_{21},r_{22}\in \mathbb{Z} \}\\
=&\left\{ \left(2r_{11}+r_{21}-5r_{22}\right) +\left(2r_{12}+r_{21}+r_{22}\right)\sqrt{-5} :r_{11},r_{12},r_{21},r_{22}\in \mathbb{Z} \right\}
\end{align*}
Which elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ are in $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$? Let us solve the system
\begin{gather*}
\begin{cases}2r_{11}+r_{21}-5r_{22}=n_1\\
2r_{12}+r_{21}+r_{22}=n_2\end{cases} 
\end{gather*}
If $n_1$ and $n_2$ have the same oddity, we can choose any $r_{22}$ an choose $r_{21}$ in such a way that $r_{21}-5r_{22}$ and $r_{21}+r_{22}$ have also the same oddity, then the values of $r_{11}$ and $r_{12}$ follow; if $n_1$ and $n_2$ have opposite oddity, then there is no solution, thus
\begin{gather*}
(2,1+\sqrt{-5})=\{n_1+n_2\sqrt{-5}:n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{Z}\text{ and $n_1,n_2$ with equal oddity}\}.
\end{gather*}

Thus the lattice/grid of $(n_1,n_2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ cannot be generated by a single "vector".