# What does $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ mean?

Tags: ring-theory

I'm reading [What is the simplest non-principal ideal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448236/what-is-the-simplest-non-principal-ideal) and the notation $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ comes up.

After searching around on this site, I found [Meaning of Z[X] set notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199701/meaning-of-zx-set-notation), which says $Z[X]$ means all polynomials with integer co-efficients.

But, that doesn't seem to make sense in the context of the linked post.
Can someone clarify what this notation means?

Comment: The ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ of complex numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$... I just copied this text from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/902926

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is all polynomials with integer coefficients with $\sqrt{-5}$ as the "variable". However, there's a simpler way to characterise the group...

If $x=\sqrt{-5}$, then $x^2=-5$ and $x^3=-5\sqrt{-5}$ and $x^4=25$, and so on.

Notice that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x^n$ is a number of the form $a+b\sqrt{-5}$, for some integers $a,b$. (We could be more specific at what types of $a,b$ we will get, but this is good enough.)

So, any polynomial in $x=\sqrt{-5}$ with integer coefficients will simplify down to an expression summing integer multiples of numbers of the shape $a+b\sqrt{-5}$, which itself will simplify down to a number of the shape $a+b\sqrt{-5}$.

For instance, $-x^3+3x+19=5\sqrt{-5}+3\sqrt{-5}+19=8\sqrt{-5}+19$.

So, $\mathbb Z[{\sqrt{-5}}]$ must be some subset of $\{a+b\sqrt{-5}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Now, let's show that it is in fact the entire set $\{a+b\sqrt{-5}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Pick some number of the form $a+b\sqrt{-5}$. This is in $\mathbb Z[{\sqrt{-5}}]$ because with $x=\sqrt{-5}$, it is equal to the linear term $bx+a$ (which is a polynomial).

So $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]=\{a+b\sqrt{-5}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.